# Incorrect data displayed when saving a query result into a session array

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following php page set up to query my database and save the results into a session variable array:

```
<?php
include 'newCustomer.php';
connect('final');


    $query = $_POST['searchDB']; 
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); // stop HTML characters
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query); //stop SQL injection
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE First_Name LIKE '$query'") ;//query the DB with search field in colleumn selected//


    if($data === FALSE) {
    $error = 'Query error:'.mysql_error();
    echo $error;
    }
    else
    {
    $test = array();
    $colNames = array();
    while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){// puts data from database into array, loops until no more

    $test[] = $results;

        }
         $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); //checks if the querys returned any results
        if ($anymatches != 0) {
        $_SESSION['names']=$test;

    $colNames = array_keys(reset($test));


    }

            if ($anymatches == 0) 
                    { 
                        echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
                    } 

    } 
?>
```

...And the following on a different page to create a combo box using the results in the session variable:

```
<?php


if (isset($_SESSION['names'])){
echo "Customers";
 $array1 = $_SESSION['names'];
echo'<select name="customers>';
foreach($array1 as $name){
echo'<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
}
echo'</select>';


}

?>
```

The query page is called when a button is pressed on the main page. It created the combo box. However, all it is filled with is the words 'array' over and over. Why is it not displaying the contents of First_Name from my database?

Thanks,

Comment: You haven't started the session anywhere

Comment: its started at the top of the main page, newCustomer which is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you output loop try this substituting "username" for whatever the name of field you wish to display is.

```
foreach($array1 as $name){
    echo'<option value="'.$name["username"].'">'.$name["username"].'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting each `$test` item to the full `$results` array instead of just the intended column value in the results array.

Your problem is with this line

```
$test[] = $results;
```

Change it to

```
$test[] = $results["First_Name"];
```

And then all should work as planned.